# How to use a signal in Angular template when the value is being called from the template itself

Tags: angular, signals

So in the current config we are running a function from the HTML template (not recommended) as follows:

**template:**

```
<div *ngIf="isPlaylist(selectedSceneItemId)">
    <p>show me if playlist is true</p>
</div>
```

**component of template:**

```
isPlaylist(sceneItemId) {
     const player = this.players.find((_player) => _player.$.id == sceneItemId);
     return player && player.$.player == this.storeSelector.blockLabels.PLAYLIST.id;
}
```

It works well, but would like to replace isPlaylist() in the HTML template with a Signal, is it possible? As you can see it is the template who is initiating the call to isPlaylist() which return boolean. Of course it will be called often so I am trying to use Signal to reduce the number of calls from the template to the component method.

(by the way I don't have to pass in sceneItemId as I have it also available in the component as in this.sceneItemId)

**so something like the following half baked code:**

```
<div *ngIf="signalIsPlaying(selectedSceneItemId)">
    <p>show me if playlist is true</p>
</div>
```

...

```
initSignal() {

        this.signalIsPlaying = computed(() => {
            const player = this.players.find((_player) => _player.$.id == this.selectedSceneItemId);
            return player && player.$.player == this.storeSelector.blockLabels.PLAYLIST.id;
        });
    }
```

Thank you.